# Im having trouble getting this txt.file to print 1-100 integers correctly

Tags: java

Im trying to have this code print 1-10 on first line, then 11-20 on the second, 21-30 on the third, etc.

But with the code now Its printing 1-10 on first line, then 10-20 on the second, 20-30 on the third, etc.

Basically I'm stuck here and  have been doing trial and error to try and fix it but nothings working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class P4C {
    public static void main ( String [] args )throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter ( new File ( "Write100Project" )); //creates a       PrintWriter object to allow us to create and write to a file.
        int integer = 1;
        int margin = 1;
        int counter = 1;
        while ( margin <=100){
            if ( margin == 10*counter ){
               System.out.println ( integer + " ");
               counter+=1;
               integer = integer+1;
            }
            System.out.print ( integer + " " );
            integer+=1;
            margin++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like `if (margin % 10 == 0)` might help...

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention im like completely new to java, been working at it for a 2-3 weeks. So what does does margin % 10 == 0 do? Would I then set margin equal to 100 so that it divides by 10 with a remainder of 0?

Comment: Tried doing this but it messed up the code badly since my while statement conditions is if margin is less than or equal to 100 which then screws up everything, and it prints infinitely. Sigh i dont know what to do :/

Comment: It's just module maths (and no, I'm not good at it either)

Answer (score 2):

When you loop over an array and want to treat certain elements differently there basically are two approaches:

1. Do something for the special element. Do something else for *everything but the special element*. In code this means an if-else in your while loop.
2. Do something generic for every element and do *something extra* for the special elements.

Which approach to choose depends on the amount of overlap. If the code for the special element is very different from the code for the other elements, use 1. If the code is almost the same, use 2.

You seem to do a hybrid of these, which is why every multiple of 10 is printed twice. Translating your problem two these approaches:

1. Print the number and a new line for every multiple of 10. Print the number for every other element. Code snippet of the while body (using `%`, I hope you got is meaning from the other answers):

```
if (margin % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.println(margin + " ");
    margin++;
} else {
    System.out.print(margin + " ");
    margin++;
}
```

2. Print the number for every element. Additionally, print a new line for every multiple of 10 (note how I need to reorder your code; you first want to print the multiple of 10, then the new line, then increment margin):

```
System.out.print(margin + " ");
if(margin % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.println();
}
margin++;
```

Besides, notice how I don't need `integer` and `counter` any more?

Answer (score 0):

With this type of thing the modulus % which shows you the remainder. Here you want a new line after every 10 so @MadProgrammer 's `(margin % 10 == 0)` is saying when the remainder after dividing it by 10 is 0

You can do this all with one variable instead of using three which should make it a bit simpler. The logic is while your number is less than 100, add one to it then print it out. If it is the 10th number in the row print a new line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class P4C {
    public static void main ( String [] args )throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter ( new File ( "Write100Project" )); //creates a       PrintWriter object to allow us to create and write to a file.
        int integer = 0;
        while ( integer <100){
            if ( integer % 10 == 0 ){ //If integer is divisible by 10
               System.out.println (); //Time to go onto a new line
            }
            integer++;
            System.out.print ( integer + " " );
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The '%' is modulus.
Modulus basically returns the remainder; for example:

5 % 4 = 1;

3 % 2 = 1;

8 % 3 = 2;

10 % 10 = 0;

i++ is the same as saying either;

i = i + 1;

or

i += 1;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class IntegerCounting {
public static void main ( String [] args )throws IOException {
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter ( new File ( "Write100Project" ));
int i = 0;  
        while(i < 100){
            if(i % 10 == 0 && i != 0){
                System.out.println(i++ + "");
            }
                System.out.print(i++ + " ");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help...

```
int integer = 1;
    while(integer<=100){
        System.out.print(" "+integer++);
        if(integer%10==0){
            System.out.println(" "+integer++);
            //System.out.println();
        }
    }
```